# Why is this question closed as off-topic

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I am talking about the question here: [While focus the element, page not get scrolled in firefox and IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52077869/while-focus-the-element-page-not-get-scrolled-in-firefox-and-ie)

I am not sure why some high ranking users thought it is off-topic. It seems like a very good question to me.

It has a problem, a desired behavior, and code that can be used to reproduce the problem, am I missing something here?

Comment: Obviously because at the time it had no code included directly in the question.

Comment: Did you add the code from the link into the question AFTER it was closed?

Comment: Yes I tried improving the question. OP had a external link to the code originally.

Comment: It should be in the reopen queue. Let the system do its thing

Comment: Ah alright I didn't know people would rather close the question instead of quickly editing the question to include the code from the external link.

Comment: @AndrewLohr If they were in the close queue, or if they were quickly looking through questions when they had just a few, it might not have been quick or easy for them to edit it. Likewise, if they were on their phone, it may have just been easier and quicker to vote. The important thing is the close process worked exactly as it should: The post was closed, you corrected the issue that it was closed for, now the post can be reopened. No real problems here.

Comment: Looks like the reopen process happened Thursday; [reviewers thought it should be left closed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/20723335)

Comment: Okay looks like all that could be done is done, thanks for the explaining everyone.

Comment: *instead of quickly editing the question to include the code from the external link* Is the license at W3Schools compatible with the license Stack Overflow uses? Their main site says, "All Rights Reserved", is there a different one for code?

Comment: @AndrewLohr: "*Ah alright I didn't know people would rather close the question instead of quickly editing the question to include the code from the external link.*" Because it's supposed to be *the user's job*. They're responsible for making their question good, not other people. Also, what makes you think that the code from the external link can be copy/pasted here? We may have a license which is incompatible with theirs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because, as the close reason says, the question did not, [at the time of closing](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52077869/1), include everything necessary to reproduce *in the question itself.*

You have since edited that user's post to bring that information to the site. At this point, that close reason no longer applies, so it's entirely possible to get the post reopened.

As stated in the comments here, the question should now be in the reopen queue, where it can pick up votes. Likewise, users that see this post might decide to go ahead and vote to reopen.

All in all, this is a case of "Works 100% by design" as this is the entire purpose of closing: Giving the question a chance to be fixed, instead of being straight-out deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did give the reopen process a few days before asking. I did not know how long it usually takes for people to see it.

Comment: Hmm.... On closer inspection, it was voted "Leave Closed" in the reopen queue. [Here's the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/20723335) Either way, people that see it from here can still vote to reopen.

Comment: Kendra, is there another place to ask questions like this on SO? Seems like I shouldn't have asked here with the downvotes.

Comment: No, this is the correct place for this question. Voting is different on Meta, check out the [What's Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) page in the help center to learn a little more. (In a nutshell, I think most of the downvotes are because it's another "Why was this question closed?" question. Some might also be because the post _was_ closeworthy when it was closed.)